# std::result_of on polymorphic functors

Tags: c++, c++11, result-of, polymorphic-functions

I'm trying to use `std::result_of` on functors. Why do I get these results?

```
#include <typeinfo>

struct my_logical_not {
    template<typename A>
    bool operator()(const A &value) const {
        return !value;
    }
};

struct my_passthrough {
    template<typename A>
    A operator()(A &value) const {
        return value;
    }
};

int main() {


    // this prints 'b':
    std::cout << typeid(typename std::result_of<my_logical_not(int)>::type).name() << std::endl; 

    // this does not compile:
    // main.cpp:24:66: error: ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<my_passthrough(int)>’ does not name a type

    std::cout << typeid(typename std::result_of<my_passthrough(int)>::type).name() << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `my_passthrough(int)` means you want an rvalue of type int as an argument, which doesn't bind to a non-const lvalue reference

Comment: Tip: you don't need `typenames` here

Comment: I see.. changing my_passthrough operator() to be A "operator()(const A &value) const" fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: If those answered your question, please consider self-answering with the solution.   Makes it easier to find for the next person with a similar problem!

Answer (score 1):

As Piotr Skotnicki pointed out in the comments, the code above works once my_passthrough is changed to take a const A& instead of A&:

```
   struct my_passthrough {
       template<typename A>
       A operator()(const A &value) const {
           return value;
       }
   };
```

Comment: or leave it as it is and use `std::result_of<my_passthrough(int&)>::type` (see the ampersand)